# How to find a code example with the map datatype in Angular 2 with es6?

Tags: angular, typescript, data-structures, es6-modules

As I understand starting from es6 the Angular 2 developers can use a datatype Map. However, I cannot find a code example.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to choose what runtime polyfill you like, but I've only ever used `core-js`. If you are using `core-js` see https://github.com/zloirock/core-js#map